# Set/Unset bell/flag state for a window

Tags: zsh, tmux

I tend to have multiple windows in a tmux session, and run long processes (such as database migrations and complex queries, etc) in one window while I keep focus on another.

I'd like to set something up to flag the window when the process is finished. I plan to do this with `zsh` functions, but I'm having trouble finding the command to set a bell on a given tmux window. I looked at `set-window-option` and I found `window_flag` but I don't know how to *set* `window_flag`

How can I set and clear an indicator for a given tmux window via a shell command?

Answer (score 3):

In order to send a bell to any terminal, including tmux, you just have to print `\a` to the terminal. You can use `echo '\a'` or `print '\a'` for that. (On shells other than *ZSH* you might need to use `echo -e '\a'` or `printf '\a'` instead.)

If a bell occurred in a window tmux adds a `!` to the window name in the status bar. Activating a window automatically removes the bell flag, that also means that a the flag will not be set if the bell occurs in the currently active window.

You can also set a separate style for these windows in the status line with `window-status-bell-style` option (the default seems to be `reverse`, that is switching fore- and background colors).

Additionally you can get tmux to show a short message if a bell occurred by setting the `bell-action` option to `any`.

---

I have the following in my `~/.zshrc` to ring the bell, if a process takes at least 60 seconds to finish:

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

typeset -i LONGRUNTIME=60

save_starttime () {
    starttime=$SECONDS
}

set_longrunning_alert () {
    if ((LONGRUNTIME > 0 && SECONDS - starttime >= LONGRUNTIME)); then
        print "\a"
    fi
}

add-zsh-hook preexec save_starttime
add-zsh-hook precmd set_longrunning_alert
```